# Bean is not recognizing the method by primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use autocomplete feature of primefaces but when I try to call bean method from my facelet then it shows an error that mybean has not such method
here is my code
Page.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

<title>Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">  
    <p:panel header="AutoComplete" toggleable="true" id="panel">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  

            <h:outputLabel value="Simple :" for="acSimple" />  
            <p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{myBean.txt1}"   
                    completeMethod="#{myBean.complete}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

MyBean.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {  

    private String txt1;  

    public List<String> complete(String query) {  
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();  

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
            results.add(query + i);  
        }  

        return results;  
    }  

    public String getTxt1() {  
        return txt1;  
    }  

    public void setTxt1(String txt1) {  
        this.txt1 = txt1;  
    }  
}
```

So when i run this code, it is showing an error that myBean has no property 'complete'.I am using eclipse and latest version of primefaces.
Am i doing something wrong here?
please help
Thx

Comment: Maybe your application is not well deployed. Try calling this `complete` method from a `h:commandButton` for example as its action.

Comment: see what happens if you change @RequestScoped into view scope

Comment: which directory your managed bean stored? i think jsf does not scan your annotated managed beans.

Comment: i did everything but it didn't work

Comment: try to place the <p:autoComplete outside the <p:panel

Comment: In the future, it would be more helpful if you copypaste the **exact** exception and stacktrace instead of rephrasing it with own words.

Answer (score 2):

> *it is showing an error that myBean has no property 'complete'*

Property? This action method shouldn't have been treated as a property in first place. This suggests that the `#{myBean.complete}` is been treated as a value expression instead of a method expression, exactly as would happen when you inline it in plain HTML like so `<p>#{myBean.complete}</p>`. This in turn suggests that the `<p:autoComplete>` tag isn't been recognized as a JSF component at all, but just treated as plain text/HTML. This in turn suggests that either the PrimeFaces taglib URI is wrong, or that the JAR file isn't properly been placed in the webapp's runtime classpath.

Make sure that you use at least PrimeFaces version 3.0 (in older versions, the taglib URI was different) and that the JAR file is been placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp.